# First tweet of a user

Tags: twitter

I'd like to see the first tweet of a Twitter user. Is this possible without clicking "more" a hundred times?

Comment: The Twitter web interface doesn't keep messages in perpetuity. You may not be *able* to see someone's first tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible using Twitter’s [First Tweet](https://discover.twitter.com/first-tweet) tool. Go [here](https://discover.twitter.com/first-tweet) and insert the username.

> #### There's a #FirstTweet for everything.
>
> Find anyone's first Tweet. Just enter the @username below to get started — where it all started.

Please note that if the user has a protected account, this tool doesn’t work.

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

http://myfirsttweet.com should do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: From the site , I almost for excited then it did not work :( *Sorry, something went wrong. This is what I have recorded as your error: Sorry, but for some reason you can't grab the first tweet for people with over 3,200 updates.*

Comment: Odd - saw the warning but it worked for me.  Says that service may be intermittent, so try again?

Answer (score 4):

[First Sixteen Tweets](http://www.mytweet16.com/) (or as far back as it can go)

Tested it myself with the More button
Here is how

```
http://twitter.com/[username]?authenticity_token=[YOUR_TOKEN]&max_id=[YOUR _LAST_ID]&page=[PAGE_NO]&twttr=true
```

Copy the link of the More Button and you are going to change the PAGE_NO to larger values until there are no more tweets (blank) then decrease the value/increase the value. Much Faster than clicking more.

The only other option is to follow the Library of Congress since they have have acquired all of the tweets since 2006 and see if/when they release it.

Answer (score 3):

Even clicking more won't necessarily get you what you want.  Tweets disappear over time.  For me it looks like everything prior to a year ago is gone.

To find someone's first tweet you could use a [historical search service](http://tweetscan.blogspot.com/2009/06/historical-search-of-220-million.html) at [Tweetscan.com](http://www.tweetscan.com), but unfortunately it costs money to use the service.

Answer (score 2):

The furthest you can go back is 3200 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twitter's advanced search operators](https://twitter.com/search-home) to search for tweets from a user, within a date range you suspect their first tweet may be (e.g. soon after sign-up). You then might have to scroll down a bit, depending on how often they tweeted and the date range you chose.